# Writing a windows forms application in c#, which is actually a server, I want to display messages such as "Server Listening", "Connected" etc,

Tags: c#, winforms, logging

I am writing a windows form application in c#, which is actually a server. I want to display messages such as "Server Listening", "Connected" etc. I am trying to do that in a `TextBox` but it is not being displayed. Any suggestions as to which tool (`TextBox` or `Label`) to use this.

```
TcpListener server = null;
Int32 port = 13000;
IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("localhost");
server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
server.Start();
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
String data = null;
//Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
textBox1.Text = "Waiting for a connection... " + Environment.NewLine;
label1.Text = "Waiting for a connection... ";
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Debug.WriteLine("waiting for conn..");
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
```

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: Edit your original post and put the code there so that it's readable. Anything indented by 4 or more spaces will be displayed as code rather than text.

Comment: This article will probably be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I want to display messages like
"Waiting for connection.." in some tool so that the user will know that the server is waiting for the client to start.. which tool should I use

Comment: If it is a server, why not drop the form, and use just Console.Out for your messages?

Comment: There are some other functionality for which the form is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you code is executed in a different thread than the GUI you need to use invoke method to execute change on the GUI.

Try, `textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox1.Text = "Waiting for a connection... "; });`

Comment: Ok, if you look at MSDN AcceptTcpClient is a bloking method. Your interface need to be refresh to change. In your case you change the interface and then call a blocking method, so the interface is never refresh until it's unblock.

Comment: I added this.refresh() after every textBox.text=".." statement and it is working now.
Thank you mate.